# How to retrieve URL query parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When I add a query parameter to a URL in the address bar, how do I retrieve it from JavaScript or jQuery? For example, when I enter `index.php?id=70&edid=33`, how do I retrieve the value 33?

Comment: Rewrote the question to clarify what is being asked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers, you may use a [`URL.searchParams` <sup>**[↗]**</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) object.

```
// Create a new URL object
let address = new URL(window.location);

// Get searchParameters property of the URL object
let queryParameters = address.searchParams;

// Retrieve specific query parameters
let id = queryParameters.get("id"); // 70
let edid = queryParameters.get("edid"); // 33
```

Browser support for [`URL.searchParams` <sup>**[↗]**</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) is as follows:

- Edge 17+
- Chrome 49+
- Safari 10.1+
- Firefox 44+

Comment: Be careful with this if you are using base64 parameters. The "+" character is returned as " " space. A regex replace will fix it as queryParameters.get("name").replace(/ /g, "+");

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer for you. I think this is the best solution for this question.
You can replace "index.php?id=70&edid=33" to "window.location.pathname" if the pathname contains the your deserve parameter.

```js
var url="index.php?id=70&edid=33";
var qString=url.split("?")[1];
//console.log(qString);

var param_val=qString.split("&");

var params=[];
for(var i=0; i < param_val.length; i++){
  params.push(param_val[i].split("="));
}

var edit_id;
for(var j=0; j < params.length; j++){
    if(params[j][0]==="edid"){
      edit_id=params[j][1];
      break;
     }
}

console.log(edit_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get complete url from address bar via javascript and then manipulate it as follow

`var address=document.location;
var edid=address. substring(address.indexOf('edid')+5, address.indexOf(edid)+7);`

This is not a perfect solution for this problem, but it will give you a idea of getting stuff to work.